# where / if any can I ask for math book recommendations?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I'm looking for recommendations on undergrad math books, in the topics of calculus, elementary set theory, linear algebra and combinatorics.

I'm not sure when / in which format I should be asking this question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are enough recommendations for these topics on existing posts that  it would be inappropriate to ask.  Just go read those posts.

Comment: Have a look at previous Questions on the site that ask for book recommendations.  Even if there isn't an exact match to what you would ask, it will help to sharpen your wording.  Such aspects as your goals and background are important.

Comment: Honestly nowadays it will be relatively rare for a subject to come up for which there aren't recommendations. It can still happen though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can ask that on the main site. But I suggest

First you search the site for similar questions. The topics that you are interested in are very standard and you can find a lot of these questions under the tag "book-recommendation" ([This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-recommendation%2blinear-algebra?tab=Votes) is what I found under the tags [book-recommendation] and [linear-algebra], ordered by votes).

If you have some special criterion and all of those posts do not address that, you may ask a new question. But make sure to make your post distinct from the old ones, convince everyone that a new post is necessary. If not the post will be quickly closed as duplicates.

Comment: To add to this, [tag:reference-request] is another good tag to search under.