# Right place to post questions ..

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I am very new to MSE. Where am I supposed to post questions like , "Book recommendations" or " Complex numbers in geo vs Barycentric " ..

Comment: Well, why not just ask it in MSE? There have been questions like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/62212/595055) asking for book recommendations.

Comment: oh..I thought MSE is only for problems and solutions..

Comment: You have a problem: "What book for [xyz]?" or "Complex numbers vs barycentric coordinates for [xyz]?". Seems to me that these would be valid questions.

Comment: @Shubhangi, you can post the question under the tags [tag:book-recommendation] and [tag:reference-request].

Comment: See also: [Where / if any can I ask for math book recommendations?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32256), [Is it appropriate to ask for references and book recommendations?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21514), [Book recommendations](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6957), ..

Comment: oh okay, thanks everyone !